# Excel VBA - Generating Part Numbers

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to program an automatic part number generator in Excel using VBA. The part numbers are in the following format: "XXXXX-XX". First five digits are serialized numbers, and the trailing two digits indicate the revision level.

When a new part number is pulled, the revision level will always start at "01". e.g: "12345-01". The pre-existing numbers are listed in column "A" starting from "A2". I would like the Macro to look through the entire "A" column and break apart the "XXXXX-XX" format and only look at the first 5 digits. Then it'll determine the highest value out of that column and automatically +1 to that value to create my next part number.

I'm completely new to VBA so my first attempt at this is as follows:
I declared Range1 as a Range so it looks through the entire "A" column and only the first 5 digits:

```
Range1 = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left("A2:A", 5)
```

If I remember correctly, the LEFT function returns numbers in text format. So is it correct to use the function "Val" to convert the text back to the numbers format? MaxValue is declared as an Integer to store the maximum value in column "A".

```
MaxValue = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Val(Range1))
```

I seem to be getting run time error 424 with the first line of codes, or is there a better way to do this? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance. Cheers,

Comment: `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left` looks like VB.NET syntax - you can just use `Left`, or better yet, `Left$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need vba for that problem, normal excel formulas will do (you can use the same concept in vba if you prefer this).

Lets say you part numbers are in A1:A100. Then enter the following formula in the cell, where you need the new product number:

```
=MAX(VAL(LEFT(A1:A100,5))) + 1 & "-01"
```

-> Make sure to enter the formula with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER, you see the correct entry when excel adds { } around your formula (that is always needed for Array-Formulas).

(Hopefully I translated the formulas correct from german to english...)

Comment: Thanks! I managed to get it to work in normal excel, However, there is one more thing I'd like to add to the formula. Instead of defining a fixed range for the formula to look (From A:1 to A:100), I'd like to make this range dynamic as part numbers are added. I was hoping to add a COUNTA function in the formula so it automatically counts how many cells have part numbers in them.

    =MAX(VALUE(LEFT(A1: $A&(=COUNTA(A:A)), 5))) +1 & "-01"

I was getting errors using this syntax. Is there a better way to do this
Thanks!

Comment: `=MAX(VAL(LEFT(A:A,5))) + 1 & "-01"`

Comment: The (A:A) range did not work because it included all the empty cells. And the max function would return a 0 if it encounters empty cells. I found another solution that seemed to work for me:

=MAX(IFERROR(1+LEFT(A:A,5),0))&"-01"

Comment: Strange. It works perfectly for me as soon as you have at least one part number in the column... Im happy, that you found a solution that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

**INput:**

[image]

In Cell B2, try the below formula and press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER. It will give you the exact part Number that required.

```
="12345-"&TEXT(VALUE(MAX(VALUE(MID(A2:A5,SEARCH("-",A2:A5)+1,LEN(A2:A5)-SEARCH("-",A2:A5)))))+1,"00")
```

Hope this is what you looking for.

**OP:**
[image]